# jquery-ui dialog is not chainable when used with concrete5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, concrete5

The following script outputs `div object dialog undefined accordion object on object click object`.  Note how `dialog` is undefined.

```
$(function(){
    var div=$('#div');
    var dialog=div.dialog();
    var accordion=div.accordion();
    var on=div.on();
    var click=div.click();
    console.log('div', typeof div, 'dialog', typeof dialog, 'accordion', typeof accordion, 'on', typeof on, 'click', typeof click)
});
```

It is being used on a pretty much stock concrete5 website on a package which I wrote.  The package adds no asseets (concrete5 speak for adding a JS, CSS, etc resource) other than the following where test.js is the above script.

```
        ['javascript', 'jquery-ui', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', ['local'=>false]],
        ['css', 'jquery-ui', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', ['local'=>false]],
        ['test', 'points', 'js/test.js'],
```

What is causing this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: where is the jQuery lib?

Comment: @gaetanoM By default in concrete5.  However, When responding to your question, I wanted to give you the specific version of jquery and I realize I have multiple versions of jqueryui which likely is the culprit.  Evidently, concrete5 also adds jqueryui by default.